# Clear queue when discord.py bot gets disconnected

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I need to clear queue when bot got disconnected from vc. Like that.
[image]

I know that i must use `on_voice_state_update`, but I have no idea how to do it.
Have tried to do it my self but got stuck on *before* and *after* states. Please help

```
    @bot.event
    async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
        if before.voice is None and after.voice is not None:
            disconnect()
```

Comment: Can you please include the code you've got so far? Difficult to tell how to help from "got stuck on `before` and `after`".

Comment: Doesn't your current code do the exact opposite of what you want?

Comment: no, it gives an error `AttributeError: 'VoiceState' object has no attribute 'voice'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is full answer

```
@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if before.channel is not None and after.channel is None and member.bot == True:
        guild=member.guild
        vc: wavelink.Player = guild.voice_client
        await vc.disconnect()
        vc.queue.clear()
```